# windows10の環境で、dockerによるPython 3.6のイメージを取得できない

Tags: windows, docker

Windows PowerShellを使いdocker上にPython 3.6のイメージを取得するコマンドを入力しましたが、うまくできません。
処理方法について、ご教示願います。

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> docker pull python:3.6
3.6: Pulling from library/python
no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.18362 in the manifest list entries
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

エラーメッセージの通りで、`python:3.6` イメージには windows/amd64 用のものが現状用意されていないため利用できません。

- https://hub.docker.com/layers/python/library/python/3.6/images/sha256-379cc4388f3b84f0299139f65c5b4e12db1bfe6d76478e25d462580d20216c52
- https://github.com/docker-library/python

3.7 や 3.8 なら windows/amd64 用が用意されているのでそちらを使うか、3.6 の windows/amd64 版イメージを作って欲しいという issue を立てたり pull request したりすることになります。

Comment: ご教示ありがとうございます。3.8でイメージの取得を行いましたが、途中で、下記の状態が発生しました。処理方法判りますか？                                                           failed to register layer: rename C:\ProgramData\Docker\image\windowsfilter\layerdb\tmp\write-set-684192303 C:\ProgramData\Docker\image\windowsfilter\layerdb\sha256\67b8339da7bcdba438620b69206841e2a3b12e876a1aba96f5c51b2ee919cb8f: Access is denied.

Comment: 少し問題が変わったので、別の質問としてご投稿いただけますでしょうか？　そうすると私も回答として投稿できます。

Comment: 判りました。ご指摘ありがとうございます。